# How to implement a single call from DB or API to be used in `generateMetadata` and `Page` component in Next.js App Router

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, metadata, next.js13

Currently I'm working on a NextJs 14 and using the App Router. And I have a server component `app/blogs/[slug]/page.tsx` containing codes like bellow:

```js
import { Metadata } from "next";

type GenerateMetadataProps = {
  params: { slug: string };
};

export async function generateMetadata({ params }: GenerateMetadataProps): Promise<Metadata> {

  // First call to DB
  const blog = await prisma.blog.findFirst({
    where: { slug: params.slug },
  });
  
  return {
    title: `${blog?.title} | Blog - MyWebsite`,
    description: blog?.subtitle,
  }
}

type BlogDetailPageProps = {
  params: { slug: string };
  searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}

const BlogDetailPage = async ({ params, searchParams }: BlogDetailPageProps) => {
  const { slug } = params;
  
  // Second call to DB. Kinda working twice for a thing 
  const blog = await prisma.blog.findFirst({
    where: { slug },
  });

  ...

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  );
};

export default BlogDetailPage;
```

The problem is I have to query twice to the DB to implement the dynamic metadata (`generateMetadata`) and the dynamic component (`BlogDetailPage`). It's kinda ineffective to call the same thing twice.

Is it possible in NextJs to query the blog from the DB only once but utilized the data both in the `generateMetadata` function and `BlogDetailPage` component?

Comment: Did you find any solution for it ? I also want to single call from API.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solution :**

Wrap your db call function in React Cache `cache`

```
import { cache } from 'react';
const GetBlogByID = cache(async () => {

// YOUR DB CALL

    const blog = await prisma.blog.findFirst({
    where: { slug: params.slug },
  });
  
  return {
    title: `${blog?.title} | Blog - MyWebsite`,
    description: blog?.subtitle,
  }
})
```

**Replace** :

> const blog = await prisma.blog.findFirst({
> where: { slug },
> });

to

> const blog = await GetBlogByID()

**Here's how your code would look :**

```
import { cache } from 'react';

const GetBlogByID = cache(async () => {

// YOUR DB CALL

    const blog = await prisma.blog.findFirst({
    where: { slug: params.slug },
  });
  
  return {
    title: `${blog?.title} | Blog - MyWebsite`,
    description: blog?.subtitle,
  }
})


export async function generateMetadata({ params }: GenerateMetadataProps): Promise<Metadata> {

  // First call to DB
  const blog = await GetBlogByID()
  
  return {
    title: `${blog?.title} | Blog - MyWebsite`,
    description: blog?.subtitle,
  }
}


type BlogDetailPageProps = {
  params: { slug: string };
  searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}

const BlogDetailPage = async ({ params, searchParams }: BlogDetailPageProps) => {

  const blog = await GetBlogByID()
  ...

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  );
};

export default BlogDetailPage;
```

**Please Read :**

1. **cache** : https://react.dev/reference/react/cache

> ***If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer if necessary)***